# R: get element by name from a nested list

Tags: r, list, extract, nested-lists

I have a nested list like so:

```
smth <- list()
smth$a <- list(a1=1, a2=2, a3=3)
smth$b <- list(b1=4, b2=5, b3=6)
smth$c <- "C"
```

The names of every element in the list are unique.

I would like to get an element from such a list merely by name without knowing where it is located.

Example:

`getByName(smth, "c")` = "C"

`getByName(smth, "b2")` = 5

Also I don't really want to use `unlist` since the real list has a lot of heavy elements in it.

Comment: Check this link http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-get-a-specific-named-element-in-a-nested-list-td3037430.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution so far is the following:

```
rmatch <- function(x, name) {
  pos <- match(name, names(x))
  if (!is.na(pos)) return(x[[pos]])
  for (el in x) {
    if (class(el) == "list") {
      out <- Recall(el, name)
      if (!is.null(out)) return(out)
    }
  }
}

rmatch(smth, "a1")
[1] 1
rmatch(smth, "b3")
[1] 6
```

Full credit goes to @akrun for finding it and *mbedward* for posting it [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-get-a-specific-named-element-in-a-nested-list-tt3037430.html#a3037597)