# Assign names to inner list from function arguments

Tags: r, list, function

I have a function

```
f<-function(a,b,x,y,z){
...
return(...) 
}
```

I am creating a list

```
list_orginal<-list(c("one","two"),"t4",c("t5","t6"))
```

I want to assign names elements that are inside the list and I want this to be same as function arguments. Instead of manually doing it like newlist<-list(c("a"="one","b"="two"),"x"="t4",c("y"="t5","z"="t6")), I want to write a something to automate this as the number of variables can grow much larger in the future and dont want to be manually adding names inside the function

I tried this

```
unlisted<-unlist(list_orginal)
```

```
names(unlisted)<-formalArgs(f)
```

I got the names assigned to unlisted (of length 5). How do I assign it to list_original(of length 3). Is there someway to map the names between the two?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could `unlist` the `list_orginal`, assign them the names which you want and then `split` them back into list.

```
lst1 <- setNames(unlist(list_orginal), c("a", "b", "x", "y", "z"))
split(lst1, rep(seq_along(list_orginal), lengths(list_orginal)))

#$`1`
#    a     b 
#"one" "two" 

#$`2`
#   x 
#"t4" 

#$`3`
#   y    z 
#"t5" "t6"
```

You could wrap this up into a function as well

```
f <- function(list_original, names_vec) {
  lst1 <- setNames(unlist(list_orginal), names_vec)
  split(lst1, rep(seq_along(list_orginal), lengths(list_orginal)))
}

f(list_orginal, c("a", "b", "x", "y", "z"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `Map` and `relist`

```
Map(setNames, list_orginal,  relist(c("a", "b", "x", "y", "z"), list_orginal))
#[[1]]
#    a     b 
#"one" "two" 

#[[2]]
#   x 
#"t4" 

#[[3]]
#   y    z 
#"t5" "t6"
```

---

It can be wrapped as a function

```
f1 <- function(lstObj, vec) Map(setNames, lstObj, relist(vec, lstObj))
```

Comment: Also, I see that you answered this question a while back - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890388/r-get-element-by-name-from-a-nested-list. I have the exact same problem , but the rmatch function doesn't return anything. Has something changed since then? Should I repost the question again?

Comment: @ACE  If the `match` is not returning anything, the structure of your data may be different.  Can you post as a new question

Comment: Sure, will do it.