# Extract list elements using names

Tags: r, list

I have a list

```
ls<-list(c("a"="one","b"="two"),"x"="t4",c("y"="t5","z"="t6"))
```

I would like to extract the list elements by names rather than indexing. Is there a way to do it?

As in

```
ls["a"]
 > "one"
```

```
ls["y"]
> "t5"
```

I want only the output "one" and "t5". I will be using these outputs to either parse it with some other string , or perform arithmetic (if the outputs are numbers) with other variables

I found a similar question asked before, [R: get element by name from a nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890388/r-get-element-by-name-from-a-nested-list).
But it doesnt work for this. Any thoughts?

Comment: D you need `lapply(ls,  function(x) x[names(x) %in% c("a", "y")])`

Comment: @Akrun, Thanks! that works

Answer (score 2):

With `plyr`:

```
plyr::llply(lst,function(x) x["a"])
```

or:

```
Filter(Negate(is.na),plyr::llply(lst,function(x) x["y"]))
[[1]]
   y 
"t5"
```

You can automate it by making it a function.

An attempt at automating the process(might be slow):

```
purrr::map(c("a","y"),
           function(x) lapply(lst, function(z) z[x]))
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `plyr::llply` here over `lapply`, which seems to give the same results?

Comment: @divibisan I am not sure about OP's data. `llply` would be more recursive.

Answer (score 1):

The following might be sufficient in your specific case, given that the component names are unique (otherwise there is an identifiability issue).

```r
## data
ls <- list(c(a = "one", b = "two"), x = "t4", list(c(y = "t5", z = "t6")))

getElement <- function(ls, name) unlist(ls)[[grep(name, names(unlist(ls)))]]

getElement(ls, "a")
#> [1] "one"
getElement(ls, "b")
#> [1] "two"
getElement(ls, "x")
#> [1] "t4"
getElement(ls, "y")
#> [1] "t5"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just `unlist` the list and use the `[[` operator, which returns an unnamed one-element vector:

```
unlist(ls)[["a"]]
# [1] "one"

unlist(ls)[["y"]]
# [1] "t5"
```

If we want to keep the name, use `[`:

```
unlist(ls2)["a"]
#     a 
# "one" 

unlist(ls2)["y"]
#    y 
# "t5"
```

Comment: Thanks! Its very short and easy to apply. i tried to avoid unlist since there might be large number of list elements

Comment: This might break for named list components, e.g. `ls <- list(a = c(x = 1, y = 2))`, not sure if that is the case here

Comment: @JorisChau You're right, a named list with named vector elements would break both our answers, but since OP did not indicate that is the case, I assumed we are fine.